# Dynamically loading content with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I realize this has been covered before, but im outside of my comfort zone and i cant seem to put the pieces toghether to fit my situation.

I am building a browser game interface and i need to load dynamically through ajax different .php files into a div when different links are clicked on a side menu.

The interface resides on www.mydomain.com/interface.php for example.

The php files reside in www.mydomain.com/interfacepages/ for example.

Here is the example code:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Only a submenu container, not a real page/link.</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Only a submenu container, not a real page/link.</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Page5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page7</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Content -->
<div class="content"></div>
```

I would like jquery/ajax to pull the name of the link (or the rel attribute as i saw done in some cases) find a matching .php file in interfacepages folder and load it into the content div.

For example the link points to interfacepages/page1.php, jquery will make the link non working from a php perspective, and instead just include that php file in the div.

I would need it to load a default .php file on page load.

Im quite unsure what to put as href.

Sorry if i expressed myself wrong, but i am missing some basics i should probably catch up to but i usually prefer learning by trial and failure (but after 4 hours i decided to come here :) )

Comment: Please provide relevant code. Links with filled href attributes, not just #s, and javascript code.

Comment: `$(".menu a").click(function (){ $(this).attr('href'); //getting href attribute from <a> //ajax loading here return false;});`

Comment: @beerwin i dont actually have any links because id build the pages depending on the answer. The code is identical to the original, except its a bit simplified and better in context. And i dont have any js code relevant to this yet, thats what im asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your js file, on click event of < a > tag, put this ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
            url: [link to your php file]
            type: [GET or POST]
            data: [if needed]
            success: function(html) { 
                alert(html); // display the response of your php function
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the head

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">         
var loadedobjects=""
var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname

function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
var page_request = false
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
  page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
  try {
  page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
  } 
  catch (e){
    try{
      page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    }
    catch (e){}
    }
  }
  else
    return false
  page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
    loadpage(page_request, containerid)
  }
  page_request.open('GET', url, true)
  page_request.send(null)
}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
  if (page_request.readyState == 4 && 
     (page_request.status==200 ||       window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
  document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
}

function loadobjs(){
  if (!document.getElementById)
    return
  for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    var file=arguments[i]
    var fileref=""
    if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file)==-1)
    { //Check to see if this object has not already been     added to page before proceeding
      if (file.indexOf(".js")!=-1){ //If object is a js file
        fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
      }
      else if (file.indexOf(".css")!=-1){ //If object is a css file
        fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
      }
    }
    if (fileref!=""){
      document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
      loadedobjects+=file+" " //Remember this object as being already added to page
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Create Menu

```
<ul class="simple-list">
  <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('phpcontents/1.php', 'rightcolumn');">home</a></li>         
  <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('phpcontents/5.php', 'rightcolumn');">about us</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('phpcontents/6.php', 'rightcolumn');">blog </a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('phpcontents/7.php', 'rightcolumn');">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The content area is `rightcolumn`; it can be created in any where of the page containing menu.

```
<div id=rightcolumn">
  <!-- your container for displaying content -->
</div>
```

See that href in each `<li>`. The javascript code has two fields:

1. One is the name of the file contain data that belongs to the folder phpcontents
2. The second field is the name of the container, here `rightcolumn` is the container.

All the best, have a try... it's 100% working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use simple HTML, you can just change the "target" attribute of all of your links to point to a frame, but you'll need to change your content div to be a frame instead. Check the HTML target and frame attributes for more information:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp

Alternatively, if you prefer jQuery. you could first attach a listener to all the links, which will then change the contents of the content div.

You can use the jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)() function to load your content in the div

Here's a relevant snippet:

```
$(".menu a").click(function() {
  var link = $(this).attr('href');

  $(".content").load(link);
});
```

Comment: target is for frames! This cannot be done in html. The second way is OK thought

Comment: You are right, my mistake, I've reworded the first part of my answer to specify that "target" is used on frames

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass your full page link that you load in href attribute of a tag.
Use this.

```
<script>
jQuery(".menu li a").click(function() {
var mylink = $(this).attr('href');

   jQuery(".content").load(mylink,
        function(response, status, xhr) {
        //alert(response);          
    });
});

window.onload = function() {

   jQuery(".content").load('www.mydomain.com/interfacepages/default.php',
     function(response, status, xhr) {
        //alert(response);          

   });

}
</script>
```