# dynamically loading content codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this html code

```
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="banner">

</div>
<div class="nav_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a  href="">News</a></li>
        <li><a  href="">Registration FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a  href="">How to Register and Rules</a></li>
        <li><a  href="">Register school</a></li>
        <li><a  href="">Register pupil</a></li>
        <li><a   href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a   href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div class="content_area">
    **<?php echo $content; ?>**
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>



 </div>
<div class="footer">
<div>

</div>
</div>

 </body>
```

now once the user clicks the links i want to load the content depending on which link he has clicked as you can see inn the code above. I can load the content as long as its all html but now that php tags are included i find it hard. how do i load the content with the following data?

```
   <div id="form_input">
   <?php    
    echo form_open('form/data_submitted');

    // Show Name Field in View Page
   echo form_label('User Name :', 'u_name');
   $data= array(
   'name' => 'u_name',
    'placeholder' => 'Please Enter User Name',
   'class' => 'input_box'
    );
   echo form_input($data);

    // Show Email Field in View Page
   echo form_label('User email:', 'u_email');
   $data= array(
   'type' => 'email',
   'name' => 'u_email',
   'placeholder' => 'Please Enter Email Address',
   'class' => 'input_box'
    );
   echo form_input($data);
   ?>
  </div>
   // Close Form
   <?php echo form_close();?>
```

is it possible?

Comment: Use `AJAX` to get respective content loaded into ur `div`...

All the `PHP` code is first processed at server side and then its result is sent as `HTML`

Comment: Refer [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956446/dynamically-loading-content-with-ajax). Its not possible without `AJAX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by nesting views that is calling **$this->load->view($content);** within my template view instead of `<?php echo $content;?>` then on the controller function i loaded the content like this

```
 $data['content']='view_name_here'; // this loads content with a view

 $this->load->view('my_template',$data); //loaded my template with $content
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

Your Controller:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function home()
    {
        $arrViewData = array
        (
            "content" = $this->load->view("site/home","",true)
        );

        $this->load->view("index", $arrViewData);
    }
}
```

your view called i.e. index

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="banner">

</div>
<div class="nav_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?=base_url('site/home'); ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Registration FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="">How to Register and Rules</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Register school</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Register pupil</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div class="content_area">
    <?= $content; ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>



 </div>
<div class="footer">
<div>

</div>
</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

your view called home.php in views/site/

```
hello i'm home
```

with this method i think you can achieve what you want if i understand you correctly

as a side note: this is an example - but you should be able to see the point

Comment: this one looks ok let me try

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider breaking your view html into a smaller "snippets". CodeIgniter (CI) makes it easy to load them in the order you want and then "show" them all at once.

One possible breakdown of views into snippets follows.

header_view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      <?= (isset($page_title)) ? $page_title : "Rapids Riders"; ?>
    </title>
```

In the next view snippet I put some URLs in the links to serve as examples using the CI controller/function syntax. Adjust to your needs. To my thinking "home", "news" and "register" are separate controllers. I will focus on the `Registration` controller in a bit.

If you're not familiar with `<?=` it is shorthand for `<?php echo`.

body_start_view.php

```
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="banner">

      </div>
      <div class="nav_bar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href=<?= base_url("home"); ?>>Home</a></li>
          <li><a  href=<?= base_url("news"); ?>>News</a></li>
          <li><a  href=<?= base_url("register/faq"); ?>>Registration FAQs</a></li>
          <li><a  href=<?= base_url("register/help"); ?>>How to Register and Rules</a></li>
          <li><a  href=<?= base_url("register/school"); ?>>Register school</a></li>
          <li><a  href=<?= base_url("register/pupil"); ?>>Register pupil</a></li>
          <li><a  href=<?= base_url("home/about"); ?>>About Us</a></li>
          <li><a  href=<?= base_url("home/contact"); ?>>Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

footer_view.php

```
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

These three view snippets are easily reused by any controller on the website. A controller based "helper" function is shown below (in the registration controller) to demonstrate implementing a sort of "templating" scheme.

The example form html will be in a file called `pupil_form_view.php` and would be used (in my example) for the `register/pupil` page.

When using an MVC app structure you typically want to set as much "data" as possible in the controller and then pass it to the view. The various vars in this file will be defined and set in the controller calling this view.

pupil_form_view.php

```
<div id = "form_input">
<?php
echo form_open($form_action);
// Show Name Field in View Page
echo form_label($name_field['label'], $name_field['name']);
echo form_input($name_field);
// Show Email Field in View Page
echo form_label($email_field['label'], $email_field['name']);
echo form_input($email_field);
?>
</div>
// Close Form
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Register.php is a controller that handles multiple pages - faq, help, school, pupil

```
class Register extends CI_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  //pupil will show the pupil registration form
  public function pupil()
  {
    $view_file = "pupil_form_view"; //the file name of a view to load
    $data['page_title'] = "Pupil Registration";
    $data['form_action'] = 'form/data_submitted';
    //form fields info
    $data['name_field'] = array(
        'label' => 'User Name: ',
        'name' => 'u_name',
        'placeholder' => 'Please Enter User Name',
        'class' => 'input_box'
    );
    $data['email_field'] = array(
        'type' => 'email',
        'name' => 'u_email',
        'placeholder' => 'Please Enter Email Address',
        'class' => 'input_box'
    );
    //output a page
    $this->render_page($view_file, $data);
  }

  //This function handles all the repetitive view loading code.
  //Just pass it the name of a view file and some data to use in the views
  //The default value for $view_data means you don't HAVE TO pass this argument if not needed
  protected function render_page($content, $view_data = NULL)
  {
    //notice the use of 'method chaining' for load functions
    $this->load
        ->view('header_view', $view_data)
        ->view('body_start_view')
        ->view($content) //$view_data vars will be visible to this view file
        ->view('footer_view');
  }

  public function faq()
  {
    $data['page_title'] = "Frequently Asked Questions";
    $view_file = "faq_view";
    //other data setting code if needed
    $this->render_page($view_file, $data);
  }

  public function school()
  {
    $data['page_title'] = "School Registration";
    $view_file = "school_form_view";
    //other data setting code
    $this->render_page($view_file, $data);
  }

  public function help()
  {
    $data['page_title'] = "How to Register";
    $view_file = "help_view";
    //other data setting code
    $this->render_page($view_file, $data);
  }

  function index()
  {
    //just load the help page when users navigate to example.com/register
    $this->help();
  }

}
```

I know I went overboard here. Hope this is useful.